# Scroller остается на месте

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, прокрутка, textview

Пишу `Objective-C. XCode. OS X.`
Есть программа, где много разных `Text View` и `Scroll View`, и возникла проблема с двумя "фьюшками". Скроллер никакими методами не поднимается при запуске программы, то есть он каждый раз оказывается в одном и том же месте, но только не вверху. Думал что при инициализации были ошибки. Но нет, другие фьюшки установлены так же, и у них нет проблем . Пытался программно поднять их:

```
[[_Scroller contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0,0)];
```

Однако ничего не помогло. Как можно поднять скроллер наверх?

P.S. Пробовал пересоздать эту текст фьюшку все равно проблема почему-то осталась

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что скролл не двигается вверх-вниз? как вы инициализируете скролл? Код бы не помешал.

Comment: Он двигается. Именно при запуске программы скролл находится не на стартовом уровне.